# How to get selected checkbox value out of multiple checkboxes in a group (can select atmost one)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes and need user to select atmost one at a time, so have a code where everytime user selects one of my checkboxes. I deselect all other and check the selected one using:

```
$('input.myclass').click(function () {
    $('input.myclass:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Just below this code, I also get value of checked checkbox and display it somewhere on page (for simplicity sake, let it be alert). For that I am using:

```
var sFilter = "";
$('input.myclass[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    sFilter = sFilter + (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
});
```

Now, what happening is `sFilter` always has recently selected checkbox and last selected checbox. like: If I have checkbox 1,2,3. Initially when I select checkbox 2, I get 2 in my alert, but when I choose 3 , I get 2,3. I presume whats happening here is at a point where code goes through all the checkbox with particular class, it stills thinks that I have checkbox 2 `checked` considering I have just cleared/unchecked using `click` function.

Does anyone has suggestion on how i can get around this problem?

Thanks

**NB:** Cant use radio-buttons due to UI.

Comment: why not just use radio buttons?

Comment: Cant use radio-buttons due to UI.

Comment: change `click` to `change`

Comment: sFilter = sFilter + (this.checked ? $(this).val() : ""); any reason why appending sFilter previous value to it?

Comment: @Ram: because, as it goes through all the checkboxes with same name, if first one is checked and second one is not, ````sFilter```` comes out as blank because it has overwritten previous value. I know this isnt full solution but I think main problem is as these two pieces of code are one above another. System still thinks 2 checkboxes are checked whereas my thinking was if I have cleared previously selected ````checkboxes```` by selecting another ````checkbox````.

Comment: @Jack: How will changing ````click```` to ````change```` have any effect? I have tried it anyway and it doesnt work.

Comment: because `click` happens before `change` so you'd get the value when clicked, not what it is changing to, just thought it could be a potential solution, that's why its a suggestion in a comment not an answer

Comment: UI?  Someone's wrong.  Checks are a universal symbol for 'take as many as you like' and radios are 'choose only one'.  This is pretty well understood by users.  Giving them checks when they should be getting radios will confuse some people if you force them to check only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution possible is that you loop through these checkboxes on the click event of these checkboxes.

Even if you loop through them on say a button's click you will be fine.

Check this Jsfiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/LMgFz/

```
$('input.myclass').click(function () {
$('input.myclass:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
 var sFilter = "";
$('input.myclass[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    sFilter = sFilter + (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
});
alert(sFilter);
});
```

If it makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like this (here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/6hm9k/)):

```
var sFilter = "";

$('input.myclass').click(function () {
    $('input.myclass:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
    sFilter = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
    alert(sFilter);
});
```

Each time you click, you update `sFilter` and then do whatever you want with it.

If you don't want to "alert" when you deselect, then try something like:

```
var sFilter = "";

$('input.myclass').click(function () {
    $('input.myclass:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
    sFilter = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
    if (sFilter != "") alert(sFilter);
});
```

Comment: problem with your solution is if i deselect checkbox, it stills gives me that checkbox number which i have deselected.